# Datadog - Lambda integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a **AWS Lambda** function which filters AWS log events from Cloud-trail and give only my AWS ROLE's events. Can I send this records only to Data-dog? Is there an API in which I can pass this filtered events directly?

Comment: Isnt datadog tile needs to be configured to show the logs with filtering only your role ones? Check the following to add datadog tile http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/awscloudtrail/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Datadog events-post api endpoint](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#events-post)? Or their [metrics-post endpoint](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#metrics-post)?

Although, it's not altogether clear to me what is meant by "send this record only to Datadog". If you use the log setup for Lambda log parsing that is described in [Datadog's AWS Lambda integration tile](https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#integrations/amazon_lambda), that should be another perfectly good way to get the data collected into Datadog, but I think it may only collect those logs as metrics instead of events.